# A query in successive percentage calculations

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I was given a couple of sums by my instructor to solve relating to successive percentage calculations. What I really do not understand is whether the successive percentage formula is better to use or do I use the conventional technique. Either way I arrive at the same answer but one of them involves hairy calculations and risky approximations while the other(the conventional way) doesn't involve so. That is the reason I am slightly worried about which one to follow. Please give me a detailed analysis about how the two are equivalent and which one do I use when. I need more theory than maths here.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by conventional technique

Comment: A detailed analysis is quite hard to give when we don’t know what you’re talking about... give, preferably with examples, a description of these “successive percentages” and “conventional” techniques